# A question on 1-D Green's function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, greens-function

The 1-D semi-infinite cartesian coordinate Green's function is given by

$$G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right)=\frac{1}{[4 \pi \alpha(t-\tau)]^{1 / 2}}\left\{\exp \left[-\frac{\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{4 \alpha(t-\tau)}\right]-\exp \left[-\frac{\left(x+x^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{4 \alpha(t-\tau)}\right]\right\}$$

where $x^{\prime}$ denotes the location of the impulse. And the solution using Green's function is

$$\begin{aligned}
T(x, t)=&\left.\int_{L^{\prime}} G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right)\right|_{\tau=0} F\left(x^{\prime}\right) x^{\prime P} d x^{\prime} \\
&+\frac{\alpha}{k} \int_{\tau=0}^{t} \int_{L^{\prime}} G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right) g\left(x^{\prime}, \tau\right) x^{\prime P} d x^{\prime} d \tau \\
&+\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left\{\left.\int_{\tau=0}^{t}\left[x^{\prime P} G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right)\right]\right|_{x^{\prime}=x_{i}} \frac{1}{k} f_{i}(\tau) d \tau\right\}
\end{aligned}$$

I have one question that if $x^{\prime}$ here is $0$, then the Green's function is $0$ as well, which means that to apply type $1$ boundary condition in Green's function will give us $0$ temperature profile. Why is that?

Comment: Well, don't you have Dirichlet boundary conditions in this setting? If so, then putting the impulse at zero physically means the entire impulse is lost to the surroundings instantly.

Comment: Yes I was trying to use Dirichlet B.C., why putting impulse at one end means it lost instantly? Could you be more specific? Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, look at what happens when $x'$ is small but positive. How fast is the impulse dissipated? Strictly speaking, all permitted impulses in this kind of setting have support inside the domain, so this is really the only valid way to look at putting the impulse at the boundary.

Comment: The equation $\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^\infty u(x,t)^2 dx=-\int_0^\infty u_x(x,t)^2 dx$ may help with obtaining some intuition for what's going on.

Comment: @Ian What does it mean by support inside the domain? Also what does$ \frac{d}{d t} \int_{0}^{\infty} u(x, t)^{2} d x$ physically mean?

Comment: Physically it doesn't mean very much, but it is a measure of the change in the "size" of the function $u$ over time. What you see is that if you put the initial impulse very close to the boundary, heat rapidly leaks out due to the large gradient between $x=0$ and the location of the impulse. In the limit of putting the impulse at $x=0$, all the heat leaks out right from the start.

Comment: @Ian So is it possible to solve this 1-D semi infinite problem using Green's function? $G$ is $0$ giving Dirichlet B.C.

Comment: The problem with the impulse at $x=0$ doesn't really have a solution, that's the point. It's a bit hard to explain why without getting into some distribution-theoretic technicalities, but the physical intuition is that you can realize it as the limit of putting the impulse at a very small positive value of $x$, which is going to just be zero at all times and all positions.

Comment: @Ian I see. Thanks for the help. I'm still trying to figure out how to correctly apply it to solving this 1-D problem but seems like I can't use Green's function in the boundary-value problems since impulse at boundary is not well-defined

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Just simple 1-D semi-infinite heat transfer with Dirichlet non-homogeneous boundary condition. I want to apply Green's function on this and see if it coincides with solution using other techniques like Laplace Transform..

Comment: You can do that just fine. You just can't put the forcing at the boundary, you have to bake it into the boundary condition instead.

Comment: But the third term of the solution requires to evaluate Green's function at the boundary $x^{\prime}=0$, see it is $$\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left\{\left.\int_{\tau=0}^{t}\left[x^{\prime P} G\left(x, t \mid x^{\prime}, \tau\right)\right]\right|_{x^{\prime}=x i} \frac{1}{k} f_{i}(\tau) d \tau\right\}$$. That will make this term zero.

Comment: Ordinarily you don't have to evaluate the Green's function at the boundary, because the Green's function only enters the solution through a convolution-type integral anyway. Unless you're trying to solve a problem where one of the forcings is an impulse at the boundary, and again that's not a well-posed problem.

Comment: I see. How should I apply boundary condition in Green's function solution equation? If not evaluate Green's function at boundary

Comment: If you actually have a Dirichlet condition then that term will just drop out anyway.

Comment: @Ian Sorry to bother you again. What if I have a flux at the boundary into the domain (Neumann BC), then why this impulse still lead to zero Green's function? Since in this case you actually have impact, not lost to surroundings/

Comment: With a Neumann BC you have an entirely different Green's function. This Green's function is for a homogeneous Dirichlet BC.